# Compartir una imagen desde mi aplicación en android, ya no funciona en whatsapp desde hoy

Tags: android, android-intent

Hasta la nueva actualización de `whatsapp` de hoy el código que os muestro a continuación me funcionaba perfecto para compartir una imagen no solo en `whatsapp`, sino también por correo, etc... En mi aplicación para `ANDROID`. 
Ahora en `whatsapp` no funciona ya, desde que lo actualizaron los usuarios, llevaba 6 meses funcionando perfecto. La imagen la cogía de la carpeta `drawable`.

El error que me da es:

> EL FORMATO DE ARCHIVO NO ES COMPATIBLE

Os paso el código, alguien sabe la solución?

Gracias de antemano.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");

                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nombre.nombre/drawable/" + Integer.toString(R.drawable.imagen1)));

                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "" + getResources().getString(R.string.enlaces));


                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: Realice una prueba y funciona correctamente, si dejo de funcionar podria ser que usas un dispositivo android 6.0?

Comment: Creo que sera un error de permisos en tiempo de ejecucion, esto es nuevo en Android 6.0: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es

Comment: No mi dispositivo es la version 5.1.1, es al actualizar el whatsapp cuando me dejo de funcionar, la actualice porque me lo dijeron los usuarios ya que les ha pasado lo mismo con el whatsapp y ya no me compartia como a ellos.

Answer (score 2):

En Android 6.0 se incorporan los permisos de tiempo de ejecución, deberías echarle un vistazo. Ten en cuenta que Whatsapp con cada actualizacion incorpora nuevas medidas de seguridad, no me extrañaría que sea un tema de permisos.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es

Espero haber sido de ayuda